# PHP Oracle issue with Global Temporary Table

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I am using PHP 7.21 and Oracle 12c. I am having an issue with a global temporary table. Sometimes the data returns an empty table, and I am only having this issue with temporary tables. I have tried in both Laravel and CodeIgniter but the issue remains. Is there something in my below code that is an apparent problem?

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$c = oci_new_connect("system", "1234", "127.0.0.1:1521/ORCL:POOLED");
oci_execute(oci_parse($c,"CALL pr_test()"));
$s = oci_parse($c, 'select * from GTT_TABLEs');
oci_execute($s);
oci_fetch_all($s, $res);
var_dump($res);
```

**SQL Code:**

```
--- Global Temporary Table ----    
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "SYSTEM"."GTT_TABLES" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "POINTS" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "NOTES" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "AGE" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "JOB" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE), 
    "SALE_DATE" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE)
   ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;  

--- PROCEDURE -----            
create or replace PROCEDURE PR_TEST  AS
BEGIN
DELETE GTT_TABLED;  
INSERT INTO GTT_TABLES (SELECT * FROM DATATABLES);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Data in temporary tables is visible to your session only, so  - nobody but you can see nor use it. Is that your case? If so, switch to "normal" tables; you'll need some additional identifier which will help you distinguish data among different users.

Also, I'd suggest you **not** to create your own objects in SYSTEM (nor SYS) schemas, which is what you currently are doing.

Comment: Without Close Connection I Cannot Get Data in Sometimes.Sometimes Its Work Perfectly And My Schema Is Not In System.

Comment: `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "SYSTEM"."GTT_TABLES"` - that's a table in the SYSTEM schema, which is reserved for Oracle.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't debug "sometimes", you'll have to do that. And yes, your schema **is** SYSTEM: CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "**SYSTEM**"."GTT_TABLES" ...

Comment: sorry Its An Example..My Scheme Name Is GSADMIN

Comment: If you say so ... anyway, why should I care? It is your database, feel free to crash it any time you find appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Its An Example and Typing Mistake Too.

```
--- Global Temporary Table ----
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "GSFIN"."GTT_TABLES"
( "ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"EMAIL" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"POINTS" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"NOTES" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6),
"UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6),
"AGE" NUMBER(10,0),
"JOB" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"GENDER" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE),
"SALE_DATE" VARCHAR2(191 BYTE)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;

--- PROCEDURE -----
create or replace PROCEDURE PR_TEST AS
BEGIN
DELETE GSFIN.GTT_TABLES;
INSERT INTO GSFIN.GTT_TABLES (SELECT * FROM GSFIN.DATATABLES);
COMMIT;
END;
```